# ¿Como hacer un autocompletado con ajax y php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer un completado , logre hacer un autocompletado pero solo me deja el nombre , ya que no estan los otros td por ejemplo descripcion como para poder agregar, esta es el modal :
[image: Modal]

Pero resulta que necesito que se autocompleten en todos los campos de tipo texto y number , para ello uso jquery, aqui está el código html y el código jquery :

```html
  <tbody>
                        <?php
                        while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                        ?>
                            <tr id="<?php echo $row["ID_CLIENTE"] ?>">
                                <td><?php echo $row["ID_CLIENTE"] ?></td>
                                <td data-target="rut"><?php echo $row["RUT"] ?></td>
                                <td data-target="nombre"><?php echo $row["NOMBRE"] ?></td>
                                <td data-target="fecha"><?php echo $row["FECHA_REGISTRO"] ?></td>
                                <td data-target="hora"><?php echo $row["HORA_REGISTRO"] ?></td>
                                <td data-target="usuario"><?php echo $row["USUARIO"] ?></td>
                                <td><a class=" visual_register" href="#" product="<?php echo $row["ID_CLIENTE"] ?>"><i class='bx bx-low-vision'></i></a></td>
                                <?php if (isset($_SESSION["administrador"])) : ?>
                                    <td>
                                        <form class="formulario-eliminar" method="POST">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="ID_CLIENTE" value="<?= $row["ID_CLIENTE"] ?>">
                                            <button type="submit"><i class="bx bxs-trash"></i></button>
                                        </form>
                                    </td>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <td><a class="btn-edit" product="<?php echo $row["ID_CLIENTE"] ?>" data-role="update" href="#" data-id="<?php echo $row["ID_CLIENTE"] ?>"><i class='bx bxs-edit-alt'></i></a></td>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
```

Y este es mi código jquery  :

```js
//Editar
$(".btn-edit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('product'); //Obtengo el registro escogido guardando el id verificador    
      $(".modaleditar").fadeIn(); // Muestro el modal

              var nombre = $("#"+id).children("td[data-target=nombre]").text()
              $("#nombre").val(nombre);
```

Como se observa tiene un data-target para hacer la verificacion en el jquery , me resulta solo con el nombre, pero si intento producir otro td que me muestre por ej un echo $row["descripcion"] y luego hago el llamado jquery me funcionaria pero no quiero llamar otro td porque destruiria mi frontend , de antemano Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando haces un autocompletado, por cada campo traes varias filas de la base de datos, entonces debes hacer un while por cada uno de los campos, obviamente con diferentes sentencias sql.

Entonces deberias por ejemplo para los nombres hacer una consulta a la bd de todos nombres, luego en el html crearas un elemento datalist con un id, en el input que quieres usar esos datos para autocompletado agregaras la propiedad List con el valor del id del elemento datalist,
dentro del datalist agrega el codigo php para iterar los nombres previamente cargados de la bd y por cada nombre crea una etiqueta option y en la propiedad value el nombre que deseas mostrar

```php
<input type="text" List="nombres">

<datalist>
  <?php foreach($nombres as $nombre) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $nombre ?>"></option>
  <?php } ?>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. Aunque esto puede resolver el problema de la pregunta, la respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. ¿Podrías añadir un ejemplo de cómo se haría esto? (idealmente con el código de la pregunta) Lee [answer] para más información.